# How do i process results from ConnectApi.Wave.executeQuery

Tags: apex, analytics, saql

Folks,
I have the following code where i want to read some data from analytics dataset.

```
String query = 'q = load "0Fb3i000000DMtlCAG/0Fc59000000pxp5CAA"; q = filter q by \'acct_id_txt\' in ["1000", "10000034", "10000079"]; q = foreach q generate \'acct_id_txt\' as \'acct_id_txt\', \'PrimaryEmail\' as \'PrimaryEmail\'';';
system.debug('query==>'+query);

// Execute the query
ConnectApi.LiteralJson result =  ConnectApi.Wave.executeQuery(query);
String jsonResponse = result.json;

// Deserialize the response and extract the data
Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonResponse);
system.debug('responseMap: ' + responseMap);

// Access the "records" array
List<Object> records = (List<Object>) responseMap.get('records');
```

I can't get the results out of it even though i know it returned data.  Here is what debugger returned:

```
VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [159]|responseMap|{"action":"query","responseId":"TID:6877800000c07267 (2 more) ...","results":{"metadata":[{"lineage":{"type":"foreach","projections":"List of size 6 too large to display"}}],"records":[{"PrimaryEmail":"test@testmail.co (1 more) ...","acct_id_txt":"10000034"},{"PrimaryEmail":&
```

I want to get the PrimarEmail but when i try to read it into a list    `List<Object> records = (List<Object>) responseMap.get('records');` it always returns null.

Comment: Take the returned JSON and feed it to https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/